# Excel VBA code to login

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns (username, pass, code), I am creating a macro to run for every row. In each row a need to go to a website, login on that website using the first 2 columns then navigate to part of that website insert the code (3 column) and download a pdf file

that's the code a created so far

```
Sub primeira()
     Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
     objIE.Top = 0
     objIE.Left = 0
     objIE.Width = 800
     objIE.Height = 600
     objIE.AddressBar = 0
     objIE.StatusBar = 0
     objIE.Toolbar = 0
     objIE.Visible = True

     Dim A As Worksheet: Set A = ActiveSheet
     Dim LastA As Integer: LastA = W.Range("A20").End(xlUp).Row


     Dim B As Worksheet: Set B = ActiveSheet
     Dim LastB As Integer: LastB = B.Range("B20").End(xlUp).Row

     Dim C As Worksheet: Set C = ActiveSheet
     Dim LastC As Integer: LastB = C.Range("C20").End(xlUp).Row

     Dim i As Integer
       For i = 1 To Last
           username = username & A.Range("A" & i).Value & " "
           pass = pass & B.Range("B" & i).Value & " "
           code = code & C.Range("C" & i).Value & ""

           objIE.Navigate ("www.google.com")
           Do
           DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

    'objIE.Document.GetElementByID("lst-ib").Value = username
    'objIE.Document.GetElementByID().Value = pass

    Next i
End Sub
```

But all my column data are in the same string, for example, for column A e get:

```
username1 usersame2 username3
```

same for all columns and I need then to be separated so I can do the login and the process to get the pdf file

Comment: if they are separated by a space you can use a simple `Split` function to do the job. You can use array to hold each username , password etc.

Comment: Where does `Z.Range` come from?

Comment: `Last` is undefined. Put `Option Explicit` on the top of your module to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that you are overcomplicating things. When your 3 columns (username, pass, code) are on the active sheet, then the following code should do the trick.

```
Sub primeira()
 Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 objIE.Top = 0
 objIE.Left = 0
 objIE.Width = 800
 objIE.Height = 600
 objIE.AddressBar = 0
 objIE.StatusBar = 0
 objIE.Toolbar = 0
 objIE.Visible = True     

Dim username As String 
Dim pass As String
Dim code As String
Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       username = Range("A" & i).Value
       pass = Range("B" & i).Value
       code = Range("C" & i).Value

       objIE.Navigate ("www.google.com")
       Do
       DoEvents
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

'objIE.Document.GetElementByID("lst-ib").Value = username
'objIE.Document.GetElementByID().Value = pass

Next i
End Sub
```